# R XML library parse without schema to data frame

Tags: xml, r, ssl

I am new to parsing XML files and am having trouble doing so.  I have tried using the following R code using libraries **XML** and **RCurl**

```
xml_data<- xmlParse('https://azure.geodataservice.net/GeoDataService.svc/GetUSDemographics?longitude=-80.191741&latitude=26.322114')

xml_list<- xmlToList(xml_data)
```

Got the following message: 
Error: "XML content does not seem to be XML" after running the xmlParse line.  To my newbie knowledge it is an xml and there is a scheme stated.

So I switched to htmlParse and received the same message.  So then I tried

```
fileURL <- "https://azure.geodataservice.net/GeoDataService.svc/GetUSDemographics?longitude=-80.191741&latitude=26.322114"

xdata<- getURL(fileURL)
```

At that point I got a SSL error and after reading at omega hat I changed it to

```
xdata<- getURL(fileURL, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, useragent= "R")
```

The error states:
Error in function (type, msg, asError=TRUE) : error:1411809D:SSL

So instead I switched ssl.verifypeer to TRUE

xdata<- getURL(fileURL, ssl.verifypeer = TRUE, useragent= "R")

This gave me another error:
Error in merge(list(....), .opts: argument is missing, with no default.

I have researched Stackexchange, the library pdfs and the documentation at omegahat yet cannot seem to get it right. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, I try using `readLines`:

```
library(XML)
xml <- readLines('https://azure.geodataservice.net/GeoDataService.svc/GetUSDemographics?longitude=-80.191741&latitude=26.322114', warn = F)
xml_data<- xmlParse(xml)
xml_list<- xmlToList(xml_data)
```